# Magento Config 404 on Multiple Extensions

Tags: magento, configuration, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a 404 error in my Magento (/admin > System > Configuration) on multiple extensions, which I install through Magento Connect 2.0. I'm thinking this isn't a problem from the extensions, but more a problem with my installation.

Have you experienced anything like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is normally caused because you require ACL permissions to view the configuration and the ACL for a user is cached in their session. This should resolve if you clear all caches, log out and back in again.